# Adding new admins using device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, admin

I need to make three admins on the web page I am developing.

Admins will have access to view all the users.

When I follow the instructions, the current user is being made the admin. I need to add two more to my admin list.

I have device gem installed in it.

Comment: Can you please paste a guide you are following? Also, are you going to add a new Devise model (for Admins) or maybe just a flag for the user to mark it as an admin?

Comment: is [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role) the guide you're using?

Comment: I suggest read the documentation: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role i am using option 1

Comment: So you should have `User` and `Admin` models. What is the problem? Please add more details - as @Thrasher mentioned

Comment: @MrShemek My problem is i need to have multiple admins. but only the current user is made the admin.

Comment: @Thrasher thank you will follow the instruction in that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to post a lot more detail. I'll take a bit of a shot in the dark:

You've made a new model, Admin, which is different from User, right? If you want new admins, you'll need to create them. Admin.create(admin_params) and such. Users are not and cannot be admins.

If you want your admins to also be users, you're better off following option 2 in the [how-to guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role), adding an 'admin' boolean property to the user model. Then you can set any user an admin with `some_user.update_attribute :admin, true` (and all the ways you'd normally manage model attributes) and test for it with `current_user.admin?`